# Why is zipWithIndex implemented in Iterable and not Traversable?

Tags: scala

I'm reading "Programming in Scala 2ed".  In section 24.4, it's noted that Iterable contains many method that cannot be efficiently written without an iterator.  Table 24.2 contains these methods.  However, I don't understand why some of them cannot be efficiently implemented on iterator.  For example, consider zipWithIndex.

```
  def zipWithIndex[A1 >: A, That](implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, (A1, Int), That]): That = {
    val b = bf(repr)
    var i = 0
    for (x <- this) {
      b += ((x, i))
      i +=1
    }
    b.result
  }
```

Why not move this definition to traversable?  It seems to me that the code could be exactly the same and there would be no difference in efficienty.

Comment: Just wanted to add a use case for `zipWithIndex` on `Traversable`.  What if you are implementing a method to choose a random element from a traversable?  When iterating over the elements, you need an index to help with the probabilities, even though the index doesn't correspond to a persistant location withing the structure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're completely correct, and your implementation should work.  No good reason to have `zipWithIndex` defined in `Iterable` and not `Traversable`; neither makes any guarantee about the ordering of the elements under traversal.

(This is my first answer on StackOverflow.  Hope I've been helpful.  :)  If I've not, please tell me.)

Comment: Totally helpful, you have +6 for that!  I'm was just making sure I'm not missing something as the chapter clearly states that the methods in the table are implemented in Iterable because they are easier or more efficient there.

Answer (score 10):

[Traversable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc/scala/collection/Traversable.html) does not guarantee the order in which the elements will be visited and only requires you to define a foreach method with the following signature:

```
def foreach[U](f: Elem => U): Unit
```

Since this method just needs to call `f` for each element in any order, it doesn't make sense to have an index on elements since the order could be different for each invocation of `foreach`.

**Edit:** This is really just an explanation, why it's not on Traversable. As Luigi pointed out in the comments, zipWithIndex would make more sense on `Seq`.

Comment: I agree that indices are not per se meaningful on a `Traversable` (consider for instance graphs). In particular, you won't be able to do anything with the obtained index *on the collection*. But you might want to have the "loop" index for something else (and be it just to mimic having `i` in a typical Java-style `for` loop), so why not?

Comment: `Iterable` (which includes maps and sets) doesn't guarantee the order in which elements will be visited either. A better question would ask why `zipWithIndex` is defined on `Iterable` rather than `Seq`.

Comment: After this discussion, it seems that foreach makes more sense on either Traversable (why not) or Seq (guarenteed order)!

Comment: I think there's a naming problem, too.  When I'm using something like this, what I want is an count that's just "this is the Nth item that you've seen".  I don't need a guarantee that I can do anything else with it.  In particular, I don't need or want to know that any particular index number is going to be the same across runs, or that I can use it as any kind of lookup mechanism.

Comment: Perhaps they would still like the "index", even if it not guaranteed to be the same each time.